# Failed to execute H2 statement

Tags: sql, h2

I executing this SQL H2 statement in embedded database H2, but I got an error:

```
  Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #13 of class path resource [db/H2.data.sql]: insert into T_DEVICE_EVENT (ID, DEVICE_ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MESSAGE, DATE_RECEIVED, RSSI, BATTERY, ALARM, PROCESSED) values (1,1,50.834015,4.377885,'71',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),70,50,0,1); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ( required: )
```

the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_device_event (
    id              bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id       bigint NOT NULL,
    latitude        decimal NULL,
    longitude       decimal NULL,
    message         varchar(100) ,
    date_received   timestamp,
    rssi            float,
    battery         int,
    alarm           boolean,
    processed       boolean,
    FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES public.t_device(id));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), you have to remove brackets:

```
insert into T_DEVICE_EVENT (ID, DEVICE_ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MESSAGE, DATE_RECEIVED, RSSI, BATTERY, ALARM, PROCESSED) values (1,1,50.834015,4.377885,'71',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,70,50,0,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

"71" seems to be the problem. You might want '71' instead.